# Can you be buried in a Jewish Cemetery if you have a tattoo?

Tags: halacha, death, funeral-burial-levaya, tattoo

Can you be buried in a Jewish Cemetery if you have a tattoo?
I.e., is it just urban legend that you can't?

Comment: Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for giving the community an opportunity to tackle this myth! (Excuse me for presupposing an answer without writing it myself.) Please consider registering your account, so that the site can keep track of your contributions.

Comment: Related: [Would a convert/Ba'al Teshuvah have to remove any tattoos they may have?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27535/1368)

Answer (score 12):

See [this Chabad.org article](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/533444/jewish/Can-a-person-with-a-tattoo-be-buried-in-a-Jewish-cemetery.htm).

In short, the answer is yes. While getting a tattoo is forbidden, once one has one there is no law that he/she cannot be buried in a Jewish cemetery.

However, every Jewish burial society has the right to enact their own rules...

Answer (score 3):

[*Gesher Hachayim*, volume 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/31174), chapter 25, paragraphs 1–2 says:

> A renowned [word I don't recognize] who has separated himself from the ways of Jewry and who has removed from himself the entire yoke of the law of the Jews: there's no *avelus* (mourning) for him... but one must bury him and work toward his burial and with dressing him therefor....
>
> But the townspeople or *chevra kadisha* (burial society) can prevent the Jewish burial of a renowned sinner as an enactment to 'stop the sinning gap'.

I doubt any *chevra kadisha* now would refuse to deal with someone for being tattooed. (But see comments on the answer.)

Comment: ... because a tattooed person is way different from a "renowned sinner," right?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, well, yes and no. If there were an outbreak of tattooing among the otherwise religious Jewish community somewhere, and someone were the leader of that pack, known for getting tattoos, and he died during the outbreak, then, well, (a) he would be a renowned sinner (though he'd have but one sin he'd be renowned for) and (b) not burying him would likely serve as a stopgap. But under most circumstances, being tattooed is, I'd imagine, not usually enough of a sin for a _chevra kadisha_ to wish not to bury someone for.

Comment: @msh210, The defining characteristic of the scenario you mention is the ring-leading rather than the tattoo.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, true. However, the only actual sin done AFAICT is getting a tattoo. Well, and _lifne iver_.

Comment: @msh210: the word in the source that you didn't recognize is פוקר, which means someone who blatantly and brazenly violates halachah. The average Jew who has tattoos nowadays is not in that category; the ringleader in your hypothetical might be, but not necessarily his followers (much less תינוקות שנשבו).

Comment: @Alex, quite. That's precisely why I gave the (admittedly odd) hypo of a ringleader-tattooee.

Comment: @msh210. A tattoo artist?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old (and can also be a very hurtful) Jewish urban legend. See [this New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/07/17/fashion/17SKIN.html?pagewanted=all) where the author tried to determine the origins of this legend. Why it's gained so much currency in the modern age is beyond me. Frankly the chabad.org article quoted elsewhere, while factually correct, emphasizes the wrong things. The bottom line is that this is an urban legend with no basis in halacha.

> The eight rabbinical scholars interviewed for this article, from institutions like the
>   Jewish Theological Seminary and Yeshiva University, said it’s an urban legend, most
>   likely started because a specific cemetery had a policy against tattoos. Jewish parents
>   and grandparents picked up on it and over time, their distaste for tattoos was presented
>   as scriptural doctrine.

Answer (score 2):

People who violate the Torah have the same burial rights as others unless they are continuous violators who have refused to do Teshuva even on their death bed. ([Shach YD 345:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=352) and [Shulchan Aruch/Rema 340:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=341))

So the question may be:  Is a person in continuous violation for having a tattoo, or only for putting one on?  Also in play, can the tattoo be easily removed?  How do we determine teshuva?

Also see: [What's the truth about...](http://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_jews_with_tattoos/)

Answer (score -1):

I heard that, in Israel, they laser off the tattoo post-mortem.

Comment: I find that very hard to believe, given the prohibition of tampering with a corpse.

Comment: @Isaac: I could *maybe* see it as somewhat like the graveside circumcision of a baby who (ר"ל) died before his bris.

Comment: @Alex You could, if not having a tattoo indeed had the same affiliative import as having circumcision, which it doesn't.

Comment: @Isaac: but is the reason for the graveside milah in order to make the child a proper Jew, or in order to not have him buried with a foreskin, which is repulsive (Mishnah, Nedarim 3:10)? (Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 263:5, mentions the reason for giving the child a name, "as a remembrance that G-d should have mercy on him and so that he should be resurrected," but it doesn't sound like that applies to the milah itself.) If it's the latter, then arguably a tattoo might fall into the same category. (After all, a Jew who fails to get a bris is still a Jew just as much as one who has a tattoo.)