# Where is the Rabbinic prohibition of tattoos discussed?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tattoo

According to [the gemara in Makkos 21a](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3875&size=2), it seems that the biblical prohibition of tattoos only extends to tattoos made for religious purpose. However, the vast majority of poskim all seem to imply that there is at least a rabbinic prohibition of tattooing anything else. Where is the rabbinic prohibition recorded?

Comment: http://dafyomi.co.il/makos/halachah/ma-hl-021.htm

Comment: What's the chronologically first opinion to say there's a rabbinic prohibition?

Comment: I saw a tosafot in Gittin that says this clearly. I also recall seeing sommewhere on this site that even a tatto that say 'I am Hashem's' is prohibited.

Comment: Rashi in your source says it too

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11794/4682 doesn't source it, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mishnah Makkos 3:6 and Gemara 21a;

Yerushalmi Makkos 3:6

Rambam (Avodat Kochavim 12:11) and Shulchan Aruch (YD180:1; Shach 180:1) both rule that one has only done an aveira if one both pierces the skin and adds colour.

Comment: Do they specifically say that there is a difference between any sort of tattoo and one containing religious references?

Comment: that isn't one of Rambam's criteria:
"כתובת קעקע" (ויקרא יט,כח) האמורה בתורה, הוא שישרוט על בשרו וימלא מקום השריטה כוחל או דיו או שאר צבעונין הרושמין; וזה היה מנהג הגויים שרושמין עצמן לעבודה זרה שלהן, כלומר שהוא עבד מכור לה ומורשם לעבודתה.  ומעת שירשום באחד מדברים הרושמים אחר שישרוט, באי זה מקום מן הגוף, בין איש בין אישה--לוקה.