# Would a convert/Ba'al Teshuvah have to remove any tattoos they may have?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, baal-teshuva, tattoo

A Jew is prohibited from tattooing himself. If a person with tattoos were to convert to Judaism, would they be required to [have the tattoos removed](http://digitaljournal.com/article/346703)?

Would a Jew who got a tattoo and later repented be required to have it removed?

Comment: I know a Baal Teshuva who still has a tattoo. He is a Talmid Hacham so it seems that there could be a Heter to keep it.

Comment: Perhaps it is impossible to remove, and therefore it remains. However if it was possible perhaps he would be required to remove it.

Comment: I just read a poem by Yehoshua November related to this [in Jewish Action](http://www.ou.org/jewish_action/03/2013/conversing-with-poet-yehoshua-november/).

Comment: There is such thing as a tattoo which isn't removeable?

Comment: @HachamGabriel, my understanding (though I have no related experience) is that it is a very expensive and painful process that can take years to complete, and depending on where it is located, it might even be dangerous.

Comment: My father had tattoos before converting to Judaism, and was not required to have them removed when he converted. When asked about his tattoos, he would tell people he was a non-Jew when they were done( and a fool besides).

Comment: Very closely related (duplicate?): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38038

Comment: @msh I was here first. ;-) Also, I don't think they're exactly asking the same question.

Comment: King David gives me some words of advice every night... my sin is always before me... I keep mine to r ember the sins to forever avoid a fall..

Comment: I was in a BT yeshiva for a bit and the opinion of the rabbonim there is that the issur is not to have a tattoo, but to get a tattoo. If you get a tattoo and sincerely regret it, then it doesn't actually matter if it gets removed or not.

Comment: @Tatpurusha can you cite an authority who holds this way? Care to write an answer?

Comment: Its no simple matter to remove a tattoo. It is normally a laser treated procedure with pain during and after, with possible scarring. I imagine for exactly this there is reason to be lenient, no source!

Comment: @HachamGabriel I believe some are under the opinion that the process to remove a tattoo also violates the prohibition of cutting/tattooing yourself, so the fact that he has a tattoo and hasn't removed might be because of this.

Answer (score 12):

According to [this article](http://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_jews_with_tattoos/) by Rabbi Dr. Ari Zivotofsky there is no requirement to remove a tattoo, although it could be considered a pious act to do so, especially if the tattoo depicts something immoral and idolatrous.

He discusses four ways of removing a tattoo, two of which are permissible, and two of which are questionable. Removal via a cream or laser surgery are permissible. However removal via injecting new dye or via plastic surgery are questionable, due to issues of tattooing and wounding ones self, respectively.

Answer (score 7):

While there is a commandment for a Jew to not get a tatoo, [Leviticus 19:28](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9920#v=28), [B.T. Makkot 21a](http://halakhah.com/rst/nezikin/38%20-%20Makkos.pdf) there is, however, a separate Torah prohibition - "Lo Yosif" - not to inflict a wound upon yourself, [Deuteronomy 25:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9989/jewish/Chapter-25.htm#v=3). According to many poskim, removing a tattoo involves "wounding" yourself.  Therefore, it is generally prohibited to a Jew to inflict pain upon himself in order to remove the tatoo.  This is why you see many Jewish survivors of the death camps still wearing the numbers that the Nazis tatooed on their arms.  Rabbi Hanoach Teller, in his book, "It's a Small World," tells a nice story about a Jew who had become a baal tshuva and went to a men's mikvah, but was embarrassed to show his naked body with many tatoos.  An older man broke the silence and, showing him the numbers on his forearm, said, "see, I have a tatoo, also."  Based on this, and the fact that a good friend of mine, Dr. Clifton Price, zt'l, a ger tzedek of amazing merit, who had a tatoo that described him as "Slim," I see no basis for denying conversion to a person because he had a tatoo when he was not Jewish.

There are sources that say it is permitted to have a tatoo removed, however.  Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, zt'l, held that a young woman who wanted to increase her marriage prospects was permitted to undergo cosmetic surgery although she would be causing wounds to be inflicted on her. He permitted it, since the surgery is done with her will and is essentially for her good.  Iggrot Moshe, Choshen Mishpat 2:66. The Talmud, [Taanis 23b](http://halakhah.com/rst/moed/19%20-%20Ta'anis%20-%202a-31a.pdf), relates an incident where one of the Sages lifted up his frock when walking through thorns. "Skin heals, clothes don't," said the Sage. Even though he was scratching his skin by walking through the thorns, it wasn't done in a hostile or degrading manner. Rabbi Feinstein cites this, and a ruling by Maimonides, Rambam, Hilchot [Chovel U'Mazik 5:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/b405.htm#1), as coroboration of his ruling.

Comment: But would they *have* to?

Comment: @SethJ Dr. Price's tatoos predated his trip to the Mikvah.  The Beit Din at the time, in my opinion, was pretty illustrious and his tatoo would have been obvious when he disrobed.  That beit din, as I recall, included R. Hillel Klavan, shlita, R. Philip Rabinowitz, zt'l, and R. Simon Burnstein, zt'l.  Given that Dr. Price was black and the conversion was in the late 1960s, the panel was very very careful.  If a tatoo had been a sufficient basis to hold up the conversion, they would have used it, and stalled until he had it removed. Note Rabbi G. Anemer endorsed the conversion.

Comment: But my question is not about preventing a conversion; it's about an obligation, as a Jew, to remove the tattoo.

Comment: @SethJ I pointed out it is not an obligation for a Jew to remove a tatoo.  How could it be an obligation for a convert to remove a tatoo?

Comment: "According to many poskim, removing a tattoo involves "wounding" yourself. Therefore, it is generally prohibited to a Jew to inflict pain upon himself in order to remove the tatoo. " Sorry to nitpick, but can you reference one?

Comment: @SethJ:  Rabbi Ephraim Oshry used the issue of "wounding" for his psak halakha telling Holocaust victims that they didn't have to remove their tatoos.  But as I note in the answer, lo yosif is used as the basis for a heter -- if a person would feel better if the tatoo was removed, then under Rav Moshe's psak, it can be done, because you can wound yourself if doing so results in your perception that you are better off.  That is also the basis for permitting any cosmetic surgery; otherwise, lo yosif would be a basis for prohibiting any cosmetic surgery.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this article](http://www.koltorah.org/ravj/14-21%20Permanent%20and%20Semi-Permanent%20Makeup%20-%20Cosmetic%20Tattooing%203.htm), Rav Eliyahu Bakshi-Doron (Techumin 22:387) viewed the removal of a tattoo as a meritorious act to avoid remembering a previous sinful life.  However, Dayan Weisz (Teshuvot Minchat Yitzchak 3:11) does not (seem to) agree that this is necessary. (This is aside from the opinion of Rav Ephraim Oshry (Teshuvot Mee’ma’makim 4:22) that Holocaust survivors should not remove their tattoos (which may have a unique status).

<sub>All citations are found in the linked article. I have not looked up any sources inside.</sub>

Comment: Meritorious and required are very different things in halakha.  So I am not sure there is a disagreement between Rav Bakshi-Doron and Rav Weisz.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Moshe Heinemann said in a shiur in Ner Yisroel 
to answer such a question "No, he is not obligated to remove a tattoo he received earlier. The torah doesn’t say you cannot have a tattoo – it only says you are not allowed to make a tattoo on your body (Vayikra 19:28 - וְשֶׂרֶט לָנֶפֶשׁ לֹא תִתְּנוּ בִּבְשַׂרְכֶם וּכְתֹבֶת קַעֲקַע לֹא תִתְּנוּ בָּכֶם אֲנִי ה)"