# Tattoos incured prior to accepting the yoke of the mitzvot

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, tattoo

I was wondering if a person choosing to convert to Judaism proper was sub-categorized into the Noachite level of observance, incurred some tattoos whilst a Noachite, later went on to accept the yoke of the mitzvoth, we he/she be ineligible because of the tattoos?

Comment: Very closely related (duplicate?): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27535

Answer (score 3):

no convert is turned away because of their tattoos. Is common for converts to cover their tattoos at all time while in public.tattoo removal encourage more damage to the body in the actual tattoo in process itself body can

Answer (score 3):

I've met converts who had pre-conversion tattoos.  It makes sense to me that a convert would not be held liable for torah transgressions that predated him being bound by the torah; after all, we also don't reject converts who used to eat pork or work on Shabbat or have relationships not in accordance with torah, assuming they no longer do these things.

As a practical matter, a convert with tattoos that can be covered (e.g. with long sleeves) may be more comfortable doing so in Jewish settings.